# Detect whether a variable has been changed within a different function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm pretty new to javascript and google maps. I have an input that, when submitted, geocodes the value and I'd like it to:

- if a map exists (something has been entered and successfully geocoded
  already), then recenter it
- else create the map centered on that point.

My code is kind of like this:

```
var map;

function getlatlong() { //this function gets the input value and then geocodes
    if(map.length){recentermap()} //if map exists, recenter map
    else{createmap()} //create map
}

function createmap(){ //this function creates the map (by editing `var map`)
    var map = new google.maps.Map();
}
```

I think I just don't understand how js variables work... my question is, how do I see if var  map has been changed if I change it within the second function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

```
function createmap(){ //this function creates the map (by editing `var map`)
    var map = new google.maps.Map();
}
```

You are creating a local variable called map that only exists in the function createmap. You want to use your `map` variable that you declared in the outer scope, so you should not use the `var` keyword:

```
function createmap(){ //this function creates the map (by editing `var map`)
    map = new google.maps.Map();
}
```

Comment: thanks. Any experience with gmaps api v3... how do you detect whether one has created a map with the `var map`? map.length doesn't seem to work by just using global `map` instead of local.

Comment: @Andypandy Try just `if(map)` instead of `if(map.length)`